# Using a convert function within a case statement SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

I am trying to create SQL query to generate a report from my database.

Every five minutes or more a new entry is added to my DB, the length of that entry the time it had been taken and the shift when it was taken.

Formerly had this code:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(DataEntry.Length) AS Length, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT MicrotecDataEntry.DateTime) AS NumberTimeEntry, 
    Shift,
    CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(mi, -360, DateTime)) AS Expr1
FROM            
    DataEntry 
WHERE       
    (DateTime > DATEADD(d, - 28, DATEADD(mi, 390, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(mi, - 390, GETDATE()))))))  
    AND (DateTime < DATEADD(d, - 0, DATEADD(mi, 390, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(mi, - 390, GETDATE()))))))
GROUP BY  Shift, 
    CONVERT(date, DATEADD(mi, - 360, MicrotecDataEntry.DateTime))
```

Our night shift is on two different days so to  keep it in one production day we remove 6 hours from that date so the night shift begins at `00:00 AM` from that day.

But now for some reasons I must remove 12 hours for the night shift and 6 hours for the other shifts. So I would like to do something like :

```
SELECT 
    SUM(ataEntry.Length) AS Length, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT DateTime) AS NumberTimeEntry, 
    MicrotecTimeQuarter.Shift, 
    CASE  
       WHEN MicrotecTimeQuarter.Shift = 'shift 2'
          THEN CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(mi, -720, DateTime))
          ELSE CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(mi, -360, DateTime))
    END AS Expr1
FROM    
   DataEntry 
MicrotecTimeQuarter.Id
WHERE  
    (DateTime > DATEADD(d, - 7, DATEADD(mi, 390, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(mi, - 390, GETDATE())))))) 
    AND (DateTime < DATEADD(d, - 0, DATEADD(mi, 390, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(mi, - 390, GETDATE())))))) 

GROUP BY Shift, 
    CASE  
       WHEN Shift = 'shift 2'
          THEN CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(mi, -720, DateTime))
          ELSE CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(mi, -360, DateTime))
   END
```

But it seems the syntax is not correct and I get the message

> MicrotechDataEntry.DateTime is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

I'm new to SQL so I don't know where is the problem. Do have any idea about what causes the issue and how I can solve it? Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I would start with some formatting and aliases. This is just a wall of text query. Also, you should use datepart names instead of the shortcuts. https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations

Comment: I think your dateadd logic is a bit odd too. What is the point of using -0? You could remove that function completely as it does nothing.

Comment: Please reduce your code to the absolute minimum required to show the problem. Specifically, use shorter table/column names and remove function calls that are not part of the problem so we can understand the query at a glance. If you do this yourself anyway, you'll probably solve your problem yourself.

Comment: @Bohemian i tried to reduce it . hope its more understandable

Comment: @ thanks Sean . the code was originally written by someone else , i'm trying to add more features to the report. But i'm going to try  using datepart instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the DateTime field in your case statement as it is not part of the grouping. One solution is to get your calculated field in a subquery and the group at a higher level.

```
SELECT
    SUM(X.Length) AS Length, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT MDE.DateTime) AS NumberTimeEntry, 
    MTQ.Shift, 
    Expr1
FROM
(
    SELECT
        MDE.DateTime,
        MDE.Length,
        MQT.Shift,
        Expr1 = CASE WHEN MTQ.Shift='shift 2'then    CONVERT(date, DATEADD(MINUTE, -    720, MDE.DateTime)) ELSE CONVERT(date, DATEADD(MINUTE, - 360, MDE.DateTime)) END 
    FROM
        MicrotecDataEntry MDE 
        INNER JOIN MicrotecTimeQuarter MTQ ON MDE.MicrotecTimeQuarterId = MTQ.Id
    WHERE
        (MDE.DateTime > DATEADD(d, - 7, DATEADD(mi, 390, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(mi, - 390, GETDATE())))))) 
        AND 
        (MDE.DateTime < DATEADD(d, - 0, DATEADD(mi, 390, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(date, DATEADD(mi, - 390, GETDATE())))))) 
        AND 
        (MDE.MicrotecProductId <> 4)
)AS X
GROUP BY
    Shift,
    Expr1
```

Comment: thanks i didn't know that . I'll try this and tell you how it went .

Comment: I tried it works now i get the expected results . thanks a lot :).

Comment: Glad I could help.